# C++ OPEN SSL Library HMAC funtion return value is not same everytime I run?

Tags: c++, openssl, hmac

I am trying HMAC SHA256 hash function from Open SSL Library with C++, However when I print the result hex values I saw that my output differs everytime I run the code. What could be the problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <openssl/hmac.h>

int main(){
std::cout <<  "Generating key for RRC" << std::endl;

std::array <char, 32> test = {0x69, 0x01, 0x01,  0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,  0x00, 0x01, 0x01,
                             0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,  0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,  0x00, 0x01,
                             0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,  0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01,  0x00, 0x01,
                             0x00, 0x01 };

std::array <char, 5> string = = {0x69, 0x03, 0x01,  0x02, 0x01 };

unsigned int lengthResult;

unsigned char result[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];

HMAC(EVP_sha256(), (unsigned char*)test.data(), test.size(),
                            (unsigned char*)string.data(), string.size(),
                             result, &lengthResult);

for (auto i:result)
    std::cout  << i + 0 <<" " ;

}
```

Comment: HMAC_SHA256 produces a SHA256 sum at the end, which is 32 bytes. `EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE` is 64 bytes, initialized with random memory garbage. If I compile and run your code, the first 32 bytes are always the same.

Comment: you are my hero, should I delete the question?

Comment: It might help other people searching stack overflow..

Comment: @Botje to that end, you might want to make an official answer to help other people even more.

Comment: I believe question is complete example of SHA HMAC hash function. it works nicely

Comment: SHould I select myself as answer or you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HMAC_SHA256 produces a SHA256 sum at the end, which is 32 bytes. EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE is 64 bytes, initialized with random memory garbage. If I compile and run your code, the first 32 bytes are always the same.